# Container docker não starta "no space left on device"

Tags: docker

Estou enfrentando o problema com o docker eu tinha um container que estava em execução quando atingiu os 10G, e sem saber disso eu de um stop nele e agora ele não inicia.

```
# docker start ambient-dev
Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:359: container init caused \\\"rootfs_linux.go:90: jailing process inside rootfs caused \\\\\\\"can't create pivot_root dir , error mkdir /home/Docker/docker/devicemapper/mnt/cbac9dcaab97a08bf5b12707240db477a871807650ba545480083cffee3e3817/rootfs/.pivot_root428549510: no space left on device\\\\\\\"\\\"\"\n"
Error: failed to start containers: ambient-dev
```

Também não consigo fazer o commit do container:

```
docker commit ambient-dev rubeus/teste
Error response from daemon: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: write /var/www/html/unifemm/unifemm_processo_seletivo.sql: no space left on device
```

Precisava dar um geito de recuperar este container, mas estou ficando sem ideias e a pesquisa no google não tem sido muito frutífera, se alguém puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso consegui ter acesso novamente ao container usando docker export e docker import e criando um novo container com base na imagem que obtive no import. Agora estou deixando a resposta aqui pq quem sabe possa ajudar alguém que se deparar com essa mesma situação.